# Cadence client and server configurations for benchmarking and scalability?

Tags: java, configuration, scalability, cadence-workflow, uber-cadence

I've written a Cadence Drone Demo application and I want to benchmark it and scale it up on a large Cadence cluster (6 nodes). What will I need to tune/configure on the client/worker and server-side of things please? I've got 2 workflow types, a Drone and an Order, and they interact, and the Drone workflow is very busy (800 history events), with lots of signals, queries, short sleeps (10s), and computationally intensive activities etc. Thanks for any help, Paul

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Do you know what is the bottleneck here? Have you set up the dashboard? https://cadenceworkflow.io/docs/operation-guide/monitor/#cadence-default-persistence-monitoring

Comment: Actually using Instaclustr's preview of Cadence managed service, what should we be monitoring to ensure scalability across all Cadence cluster nodes and no bottlenecks? We have some metrics exposed on the console at this point but not all of them yet. Paul

Comment: So what do you have for monitoring? 
Not all of them in the docs are critical, but most of them are quite important. I would encourage to have them.

Comment: For your question of what should be monitored for scalability— most of the latency are important for monitoring latency, especially persistence/frontend/history  Api . And also task schedule to start latency